# How does Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HelicalPipe work?

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

I have a doubt about the functionment of the `Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.HeatTransfer.HelicalPipe` function.
I want to model an helical heat exchanger using the `DynamicPipe` of the `Modelica Standard Library`. Does the function allow me to specify such a geometry in order to simulate it with my boundary conditions ? Or does the function just return the heat transfer coefficient with geometry parameters in inputs ? If that's the case is it possible to simulate a flow in a pipe which is helical without using the `Bends` of the `Modelica Standard Library` ?

Thanks for your responses and have a good day,
Maxime

Comment: Did you check the documentation under `Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.Utilities.SharedDocumentation.HeatTransfer.HelicalPipe`?

Comment: Yes, but what is not clear is if I use this in a model which is already existing and calculate the temperature of a fluid in a **DynamicPipe** taking into account forced and natural convection for example, does this function can be used to modify the geometry of the **DynamicPipe** from straigth to helical in order to have different temperature. Or does the function just return outputs for specified inputs

Comment: I am no fliud expert, so I have no idea about that. But in general every function in Modelica just returns outputs for given inputs. Functions have no states.